# Android Firebase Error at Creating Users

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a Firebase Chat application and I can't seem to find the reason why I get the error when I am creating users. In the Firebase Console, Sign-In Method is Enabled on Email/Password.

I have tried:

-Introducing users from the Firebase console, that works

-Introducing legit credentials, so I won't raise up invalid password, username, email errors

-I tried using the code provided by the Android Assistant Firebase, the same error is given to me

Could someone point where I may be wrong?

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextInputLayout mDisplayName;
private TextInputLayout mEmail;
private TextInputLayout mPassword;
private Button mCreateBtn;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mDisplayName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.reg_display_name);
    mEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    mPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    mCreateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg_create_btn);

    mCreateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String display_name = mDisplayName.getEditText().getText().toString();
            String email = mEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
            String password = mPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();


                register_user(display_name, email, password);
        }
    });
}

private void register_user(String display_name, String email, String password) {

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

           if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();
           }
           else {
               Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You got some error with creating the new user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: And where are the message error/console? Post error message please.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @B.Ania did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

Try this one I think you have forgotten  `addOnCompleteListener(Executor executor, OnCompleteListener listener)`, the Executor determines the thread that will be used to invoke the listener.

Comment: Thank you, this helped! As well as enabling the Google Identity Toolkit API, since it told me it has not been configured for this project. I must have missed this.

Comment: @AndréKool I think you need to take a better look

Comment: You are completely right, my bad. Coffee hasn't fully kicked in yet :(